# Detect open slide in carousel menu and prevent to fire a click event from the top menu again

Tags: jquery, menu, onclick, carousel

I have a **carousel menu** that works correctly (when you click on a title the relative slide opens). I also have a **top menu** with an element that if clicked triggers the click on a title of the carousel menu making a slide open as well as a click occurred directly on the carousel menu. It works but there's a small problem:

[image: Initial status of the page] "Initial status of the page"

If I click on the element of the top menu the carousel menu slide opens correctly, then if I open another slide and click on the top menu again it opens the slide again.

[image: First click] "First click on "Contatti" and its correct effect"

The problem is if I click twice on the element of the top menu. The first time the slide in the carousel menu will open correctly, at that point nothing else should happen, unless a new slide is opened by a user and the user clicks on the element of the top menu for opening the slide again. Instead at the second click on the top menu element the slide on the left opens.

[image: Second click] "Second click on "Contatti" shouldn't do anything, instead it opens the slide on the left"

I don't why and I don't want this to happen. I'm thinking of a way to solve the problem. Using a counter or set a Boolean value on the click event wouldn't help I think, I would need to precisely detect if the slide is open and then prevent further action on the click of the top menu, but then if the user browses another slide and clicks on the top menu again, the click event should be enabled again.

The **HTML** of the **top menu** looks like this:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index-buono.html' id="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>

    <li><a href='#' id="prodotti"><span>Prodotti</span></a></li>

    <li><a href='#' id="info"><span>Info</span></a></li>

    <li class='last'><a href='#'id="contact" ><span>Contatti</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The **HTML** of the **accordion menu** looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="demo">
    <ol>
     ...................
      <li id="contattaci">
        <h2><span>Contattaci</span></h2>
          <div>
            <iframe src="form.php"width="625px" height="400px" ></iframe>
          </div>
          p class="ap-caption">e-mail</p>
      </li>
    ....................
    </ol>
  </div>
<div>
```

This is the **JQuery** code I use for making the slide (with id="contattaci") of the carousel menu open when a user clicks on the element(with id="contact") in the top menu:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#contact', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("#contattaci h2").click(); 
});
    });
```

**I recommend to see the [real page](http://tinyurl.com/qzuuxpb) in order to reproduce the problem, understand better and try to find a solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw on your website that an opened slide gets a "selected" class as follows :

hidden slide :

```
<li id="contattaci" class="slide" ...>
```

shown slide :

```
<li id="contattaci" class="slide selected" ...>
```

so you just have to test if the slide is already opened on `#contact` click. You can use the JQuery method `.hasClass()`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#contact', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!$("#contattaci").hasClass('selected')) { // if #contattaci does NOT have class .selected
            $("#contattaci h2").click();
        }
    });
});
```